# url rewrite htaccess issue

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have urls:

> http://127.0.0.1/myfolder/index.php
>
> http://127.0.0.1/myfolder/index.php?error=1...

How can I make

> http://127.0.0.1/rewritedpath/ (index.php)
>
> http://127.0.0.1/rewritedpath/error/1 (index.php?error=1)

I've ried

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?rewritedpath/ /myfolder/index.php
RewriteRule ^/?rewritedpath/error/([0-9]+)$ /myfolder/index.php?error=$1
```

But this is not working. What's wrong here? Thanks

UPDATED

---

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?rewritedpath/error/([0-9]+)$ /myfolder/index.php?error=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?rewritedpath/ /myfolder/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Your htaccess is fine. Maybe it's a problem of the expectation? This will *not* transform your urls to `http://127.0.0.1/rewritedpath/` automatically. It works the other way round: requesting `http://127.0.0.1/rewritedpath/` will rewrite it to `http://127.0.0.1/myfolder/index.php` - Meaning your html should now start targeting the SEO-URL if you want that URL to be visible in the adressbar.

Comment: @dognose when I remove second rewrite then first is working, when I remove first, then second is working xd

Comment: Then just try to mark them with `[L]`, but move the more specific rule (second one) to the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below rule,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?rewritedpath/ /myfolder/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?rewritedpath/error/([0-9]+)$ /myfolder/index.php?error=$1 [L]
```

Comment: First rule includes second rule, thus (due to `[L]`) second one would never be triggered. Change the Order.

Comment: @AbhishekGurjar any, but not works, view my updated code, is everything ok?

Comment: Ah thank you so much, It was problem with locallhost

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you myfolder located at

/var/www/html/myfolder

1. Make sure `index.php` in myfolder
2. create `.htaccess` in /var/www/html/rewritedpath/
3. Write this code in your newly created `.htaccess` file

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../myfolder/index.php?params=$1 [NC]`

4. Write this login in `index.php` file which is located at myfolder

`$get = explode("/",$_GET['params']);`

in $get at $get[0] youi will got your key error and $get[1] you will get your value.

It will parse all url parameters in array.